# List all the subsets of a set containing an empty set

Tags: elementary-set-theory, self-learning

I would like someone to confirm whether this is correct or not. Thanks!

A = { 1, 2, ∅ }
list all the subsets of set A.

since the number of subsets in one set = 2^(cardinality of the set), and
the cardinality of 3 in set A. We have 2^(3) = 8, 8 possible subsets.

all 8 possible subsets are : {1}, {2}, {∅}, {1, 2}, {1, ∅}, {2, ∅}, {1, 2, ∅}, and ∅

Comment: You are correct.

Comment: Thank you! And just to confirm that { } and ∅ are the same thing, right?

Comment: Yes, these typically both denote the empty set.